# Mobile app and authentication to REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, mobile, cordova

I am building a mobile app for my web application. I have decided to use [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) , So basically it will be single page web app. I have also made a REST API server which uses key and secret to verify each request. In web app I can use key and secret to make request to my api server, But how do I do it with in mobile app? It would be bad idea to store key and secret in mobile app (May be it is bad idea for web app aswell). I am thinking of changing Authentication process in api server aswell. What should be the best way to call this rest api server from mobile app and authenticate these requests. Should I generate tokens for each user request and verify with key and secret? I think I will not need oauth as this service will be for my webapp and mobile apps only, we don't have need to allow others third party service to access our api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I generate tokens for each user request and verify with key and secret?

Yes.

It might be worth using OAuth if you can use an existing implementation from somewhere. It's a standard protocol, so is more likely to be secure than something you invent yourself.

It also means that if you ever want to let third party apps log in in future, you can. You might not think you will ever need it, but you never know. It's also a good idea so that if you ever work on another project that needs oauth, you have had practise.